# Homotopy for Torus into coffee mug

Tags: homotopy-theory

I just saw the example of coffee mug and torus on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Formal_definition) about "Homotopy" and I asked myself a few questions regarding this example:

$X=T^3$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^3$ are topological spaces and I have $f,g: X\rightarrow Y$. My first question is: What do they mean with $f$ " takes the torus to the embedded surface-of-a-doughnut shape". So does $f$ map all points of $T^3$ to the surface of the starting doughnut? If yes wouldn't then be $f$ not continuous? Maybe one can write down $f$ explicitly and then it get's clear?

Could one also take for $X=\mathbb{R}^3$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be continuous?  Nearby points are mapped to nearby points.

Comment: What's your definition if $T^3$?  (Also, note that you probably mean $T^2$; the surfaces in question - the surface of the coffee cup and the surface of the donut - are two-dimensional objects, not three-dimensional.)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by your second question:  Could one also take for $X=\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki , ok let's consider $X=T^2$, such that both maps are defined going from the surface of the torus to $R^3$. But how do I construct $f$ explicitly in this case? Do I map all points on the surface of the torus to a torus in 3D and outside of the 3D torus I set everything to zero? The map would then obviously not be continuous... I hope I explained well where I have troubles.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the 3D torus"?  The domain of the map is just the torus.

Comment: Okay, maybe it confused me that $Y=\mathbb{R}^3$. The Codomain is probably only the three dimensional torus. So writing $f:T^2\rightarrow T^3$ and also writing $f:T^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is both correct.